# JavaScript: Function returns an array reordered based on results of Callback Function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a function that accepts an array and a callback. The callback will return a boolean value and the function will iterate through the array and perform the callback on each element. In doing that, the function returns a new array, where all the elements that yielded a return value of true come first in the array, and the rest of the elements come second.

```
function prioritize(array, callback) {
  let newArr = []
  array.forEach(ele => {
    if (callback(ele) === false) {
      newArr.push(ele);
    } else { 
      newArr.unshift(ele);
    }
  });
  return newArr;
}
```

Everything looks good until I run a test case where the prioritize function should return an array that is reordered based on results of calling the callback function with each item.

For example, when I run:

```
function startsWithS(str) { return str[0].toLowerCase() === 's'; }
const tvShows = ['curb', 'rickandmorty', 'seinfeld', 'sunny', 'friends']
console.log(prioritize(tvShows, startsWithS));
```

// should log: **['seinfeld', 'sunny', 'curb', 'rickandmorty', 'friends']**

Instead, I get: **['sunny', 'seinfeld', 'curb', 'rickandmorty', 'friends']**, where 'sunny' and 'seinfeld' should be switched. Not sure what I am missing here but any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use `sort`? `tvShows.sort((a, b) => startsWithS(b) - startsWithS(a))`

Comment: @Nick JS `sort()` is not necessarily a stable sort depending on the implementation

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into that. I'm open to other and possibly more efficient implementations as well. Is sort ECMAScript 6?

Comment: @ElanHamburger it's not all that bad these days ~ https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_array_sort_stable

Comment: @Nick fair enough. As a personal choice I wouldn't rely on something that isn't in the standard as a semantic guarantee as OP requests, but as of ES 2021 stability _is_ actually in the standard, so I guess you win. https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.sort

Comment: @ElanHamburger perhaps I should delete my comment and repost it next year :-)

Comment: @Nick I looked it up and stability was actually added in the 2019 standard, so I guess I'm double wrong

Comment: @ElanHamburger the `caniuse` data certainly says all modern browsers (and I deliberately exclude IE from that definition) have supported it since earlier this year (Edge) or even back as far as 2008 (Firefox) but typically in the 2017-2018 timeframe. Still it comes down to what you have to support and so it may not be suitable for all use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code reaches "seinfeld" before "sunny", and unshifts it to the beginning of the array. Then when it gets to "sunny", it puts sunny at the beginning of the array, before seinfeld.

The way I would fix this is to have two arrays initialised in your function:

```
let trues = [];
let falses = [];
```

If the callback returns true for an element, `.push` it to the `trues` array. Otherwise `.push` it to the `falses` array. Then, at the end of your function, concatenate the two:

```
return(trues.concat(falses));
```

Comment: Nice, but you probably want `trues.concat(falses)`

Answer (score 0):

Well just think about how it works:

```
curb -> false -> push: ["curb"];
rickandmorty -> false -> push: ["curb", "rickandmorty"];
seinfield -> true -> unshift: ["seinfield", "curb", "rickandmorty"];
sunny -> true -> unshift: ["sunny", "seinfield", "curb", "rickandmorty"];
friends -> false -> push: ["sunny", "seinfield", "curb", "rickandmorty", "friends"];
```

You can fix this by getting the last index of a word that starts with s, and then adding the spot there:

```js
const filter = str => str[0].toLowerCase() === "s";
const arr = ["curb", "rickandmorty", "seinfield", "sunny", "friends"];

function prioritize(array, callback) {
  let newArr = []
  array.forEach(ele => {
    //better to have positive conditionals
    if (callback(ele) === true) {
      const index = newArr.filter(callback).length;
      console.log(index);
      newArr.splice(index, 0, ele);
    } else {
      newArr.push(ele);
    }
  });
  return newArr;
}

console.log(prioritize(arr, filter));
```

You could also make the function create two arrays one with s starting shows and the other not and just concat them.

Answer (score 0):

```
const prioritize = (array, callback) => {
  let falses = [];
  let trues = [];
  array.forEach(el =>{
    if(callback(el)){
      trues.push(el);
    } else {
      falses.push(el);
    }
  });
  return trues.concat(falses);
}
```